# Block backlinks to search results page

Tags: seo, backlinks

For some strange reasons there are hundreds of thousands links from SPAMMY sites linking to search results page of our site.

They link to search terms that doesn't even exist on our site. [image: see screenshot]

Comment: What is the purpose of blocking then?  If it for site performance, user experience, SEO, or something else?

Comment: Biggest question would be are those ?s=strings indexable?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller SEO purposes, they are messing up my link profile

Comment: @SimonHayter i don't know but they are dofollow

Comment: Err? I'm asking if your pages are indexable... e,g do your pages that are accessible  by /?s=overload follow best practices? e.g noindex, robots.txt - Google can't punish pages that are not indexed.

Comment: @SimonHayter search result pages are not index by search engines i have also blocked /?s= in my robots.txt

Comment: Then why are you worried? Google does not factor links to pages that are not indexed, in, or out, therefore your link diversity is unaltered.